# Is there a way of permanently disabling a device without using a GPO / Device Manager?

Tags: windows-10, audio, windows-registry, intel

So I have an issue with the Intel Smart Sound for USB Audio device keeps getting re-enabled and is causing all kinds of USB issues. We can solve it by manually disabling the device; however this doesn't scale well and the system we use for updating graphics drivers etc. keeps re-enabling it (As it's supposed to in all fairness)

Is there a way we can make the disabling permanent? I was wondering if there is there a way of disabling via the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of another way to disable a device
permanently than to disconnect it physically...

As the device returns after each boot when it's detected during the boot,
you could set up a boot script that will disable it each time.

Possible tools are :

- [DevCon Disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-disable).
  A standalone version of devcon is available from Github at
  [DevCon-Installer](https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer).
- [Nirsof DevManView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html)
  as described in
  [How to disable, enable, and uninstall a device from command-line on Windows](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/disable-enable-uninstall-device-command-line.html).